# If I have my desktop background set to slideshow, is it possible to create a program to output the filename and location of the current image?

Tags: windows, windows-7

I'm not well versed in programming when it comes to things like these and would like to understand more about if such a thing is possible. In the end I'd just need to output to be displayed where I could just copy and paste the location but it might be less problematic to just browse manually instead

Comment: Use the `IDesktopWallpaper::GetWallpaper` method.

Comment: Thanks @RaymondChen. I don't understand this kind of code or any of the windows api, so i might as well start now. how can i mark this as an answer?